# ember-i18n translate text with double curly braces

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

How to translate this Ember template text:

> `<p>The {{user.name}}'s tasks in "{{project.name}}"</p>`

**Update**

The problem is solved:

In template:

`{{t "The (user.name)'s tasks in '(project.name)'" username=user.name projectname=project.name}}`

In translations:

```
export default {
  "The (user.name)'s tasks in '(project.name)'":`Задачи {{username}} в "{{projectname}}"`
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. what are you trying to translate it to? Don't assume we just know what you are trying to do. Please explain your code to us and tell us more about what you are attempting to achieve. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask another question because this question is shockingly below stackoverflow's standards.

Comment: What are you trying to translate it to? Please explain your code to us and tell us more about what you are attempting to achieve

Comment: You need to explain more. What language are you using? What library is this. What is the ultimate goal of the code? What steps have you tried? You need to assume that everyone who is going to help you has no idea what you are doing. Because everything that you have posted doesn't give us any context. Anyone who reads this question will have no idea whats going on. You need to **Explain More!**

Comment: I have a library in the title - ember-i18n. I want translate from English to Russian. To simple translate text i use {{t "Task"}}. How to translate to Russian with using ember-i18n this text: <p>The {{user.name}}'s tasks in "{{project.name}}"</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translation file:

```
export default {
  userTasks: `The {{username}}'s tasks in "{{projectname}}"`
}
```

Template:

```
<p>{{t "userTasks" username=user.name projectname=project.name}}</p>
```

Comment: I tried to do so, but there is an error: "Assertion Failed: A helper named "user.name" could not be found"

Comment: It works, but it is necessary to remove the brackets <p>{{t "userTasks" username=user.name projectname=project.name}}</p>